# Forward declare typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

**Background**

I am working on creating a C++ binding to a Data Modeling Language. Part of this involves reading in a set of type definitions and translate it to C++ typdefs. At the moment, in my case there are around a 100 of these.

**Problem**

In the file I am reading the type definitions are not sorted in any way. So I might end up with defining a type to another type that hasn't been defined yet.

In C++ the problem basically is this:

```
typedef typeA typeB;
typedef typeC typeA;
typedef double typeC;
```

So obviously this will not work, but can I forward declare these in any way?

A possible solution is of course for me to process these definitions before creating the C++ file:

```
typedef double typeC;
typedef typeC typeA;
typedef typeA typeB;
```

But my questions is still, **can I forward declare typdefs to make this work**?

Comment: IOW, you need to sort your input type definitions in a topological order

Answer (score 1):

You can't forward declare a typedef, but you can create aliases for incomplete types if it helps (I don't understand exactly what's the problem, but the OP mentioned the fact the his types are not defined - I'm authorized to think that they have been declared at least).
That said, I would use an using declaration instead of a typedef nowadays:

```
typedef A B;
// Equivalent to
using B = A;
```

The following is an example of a forward declared (incomplete) type for which an alias is created:

```
struct A;
using B = A;
B* foo;
struct A {};
int main() { foo = nullptr; }
```

Comment: +1 for preferring `using` over `typedef`... The only reason to stick with `typedef` would be compatibility with legacy code, and you'd forfeit the use of templates. Get in the habit of `using`

Comment: I think I understand your point here. But the typedefs are not declared before defined (in the data modeling language file). I could do like you said, but it wouldn't be much simpler than just sorting the typedefs.

Answer (score 1):

No, a typedef *cannot* be forward-declared.

Class types, union types, and (since C++11) enum types can be forward-declared using the `class` or `struct` keyword, the `union` keyword, and the `enum` keyword, respectively. For example

```
class Foo;  // forward declaration
Foo* make_foo();
class Foo {
   // ...
};
```

However, typedefs cannot be forward-declared even if you know for sure that the type is a class, union, or enum. For example, this will not work:

```
class Bar { /* ... */ };
class Foo;
typedef Bar Foo;
```

The reason is that forward-declaring `Foo` implicitly declares it to be the same type that would be defined by a later `class Foo { /* ... */ };` definition, therefore it is distinct from all previously defined types, so when you later say `typedef Bar Foo;`, you are contradicting what you said earlier.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will just sort all the typdefs, and get rid of this problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `typedef` for forward declaration. But to use

```
typedef typeA typeB
```

`typeA` should have forward declaration first:

```
struct typeA;
typedef typeA typeB
```